# Creating a NearestFunction that returns an index

Tags: functions, options, performance-tuning

I use `Nearest` repeatedly for large data sets. For example

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 3}];  
Nearest[pts, {0, 0, 0}]
```

I am interested in the index of the nearest point, so I use

```
ind = First@Nearest[pts -> Automatic, {0, 0, 0}]
```

How do I create a `NearestFunction` that can return an index. Returning a point is easy

```
nf = Nearest[pts];  
nf[{0, 0, 0}]
```

but there is seemingly no option to return the index?

Answer (score 14):

From documentation:

> `Nearest[{elem₁ -> v₁, elem₂ -> v₂, …}, x]` gives the `vᵢ` corresponding to the `elemᵢ` to which `x` is nearest.
>
> `Nearest[data]` generates a `NearestFunction[…]` that can be applied repeatedly to different `x`."

We can use these two points as below.

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 3}];
nf = Nearest[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]]];

In[380]:= nf[{0, 0, 0}]

(* Out[380]= {973} *)

In[381]:= pts[[973]]

(* Out[381]= {0.0842448696868, 0.00699056059919, -0.0130070656885} *)
```

Comment: Or just use `Automatic`, as in the question.  This seems to work: `Nearest[RandomReal[1, 10] -> Automatic]`.  It saves the `Thread` and the `Range@Length[...]`

Answer (score 9):

In version 11, you can also use `pts -> "Index"`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 3}];  
nF  = Nearest[pts -> "Index"];
nF[{0,0,0}]
```

> {264}

You can have a `NearestFunction` returning multiple properties:

```
nF2 = Nearest[pts -> {"Index", "Element","Distance"}];
nF2[{0,0,0}]
```

> {{264, {0.0284666, -0.0158014, -0.100454}, 0.105599}}

Comment: Is this any different from `Automatic` or just an alias?  Oh, nice update, I see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it seems it is not just an alias. For example, `Nearest[pts->{Automatic, "Element","Distance"}]`  doesn't work but `Nearest[pts->{"Index", "Element","Distance"}]` does.