# How can I calculate the correlation dimension and/or the Lyapunov exponent of a time series using Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a pretty long time series (4000 data points).

How can I calculate the [Correlation dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_dimension) and/or [Lyapunov exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) for such data?

Please also advise on how to import the data as well.

Comment: What is the format of the data? Depending on the sort of file it is in you can often simply define `datain=Import["/yourdirectory/yourfile.dat"]` but you should look at the options for `Import` which may help.

Comment: It will be also helpful if you supply us some example data to play with. You can upload your data somewhere.

Comment: I fail to see down-voter's reasoning.

Answer (score 8):

**(*EDIT: Another implementation has been added at the end of this post.*)**

---

I employ `Nearest` to implement the algorithm for correlation dimension, $d_C$. Here's how it goes:

Make some data

```
data = RandomReal[1, {4000, 2}];
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

I define the correlation sum using `Nearest`

```
corr[r_] := Total[Table[
Length[Drop[Nearest[Drop[data, i - 1], data[[i]], {All, r}], 
 1]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]]
```

The `Drop` between `Length` and `Nearest` is because `Nearest[dataset,dataset[[i]]]` results in `dataset[[i]]` for any `i`.

For a comparison I define also the correlation sum in the regular way

```
corrSum[r_] := 
Sum[HeavisideTheta[r - EuclideanDistance[data[[i]], data[[j]]]], {i, 
1, Length[data]}, {j, i + 1, Length[data]}]
```

(I don't care about the multiplicative constant in front of these sums because later I will take a logarithm which will result in just a vertical offset not influencing the slope and hence the correlation dimension.)

I evaluate the two approaches:

```
my = Log[10, N@Table[{r, corr[r]}, {r, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.83536, Null}

```
classic = Log[10, N@Table[{r, corrSum[r]}, {r, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {187.483, Null}

My implementation is 100 times faster than the straightforward approach, and yields the correct result:

```
my == classic
```

> True

Now only some plotting and fitting:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[my, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}];
fit = LinearModelFit[Drop[my, 1], x, x];
{min, max} = MinMax@First@Transpose@my;
plot2 = Plot[Normal[fit], {x, min, max}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot1, plot2, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLabel -> "corr_dim=" <> ToString@Normal[fit][[2, 1]], 
FrameLabel -> {"log(r)", "log[C(r)]"}]
```

to achieve

[image]

The idea is to fit a line in the linear part of the $\log C(r)$ vs. $\log r$ region, hence for the dataset `data` I had to `Drop[my,1]`.

The correlation dimension $D_C$ will usually give a value slightly smaller than the correct fractal dimension; here, $d_C=1.96$ instead of 2, which is not that bad.

The set of values of `r` that I used above is only exemplary and should be adjusted in a particular case. The same applies to chosing a subset of `my` for fitting a line.

I ran the exact same code on the Duffing attractor (also 4000 points)

[image]

and achieved

[image]

i.e. $d_C=1.33$; time elapsed

> {5.5014, Null}

---

**EDIT:** This is directly inspired by [an answer given by C. E. to a different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126054/22013). In fact, I admit I stole even his names of symbols and functions.

This is a `SparseArray` approach, so I refer to it as SA:

```
corrSA[data_, r_] := Module[{dist, eliminate, pos},
  dist = DistanceMatrix[data, DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance];
  eliminate = 
   UnitStep[ConstantArray[r^2, {Length@data, Length@data}] - dist] - 
    IdentityMatrix[Length@data];
  pos = SparseArray[eliminate]["NonzeroPositions"];
  0.5 Length@pos
  ]
```

Note that I employed `DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance` in `dist` because it turns out it is faster than `EuclideanDistance`. Accordingly, I had to put `r^2` in `eliminate`.

Sadly, for random data this takes more time than `corr[r]` took:

```
mySA = Log10[N@Table[{r, corrSA[data, r]}, {r, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.837545, Null}

**On the other hand, it required substantially less time for the Duffing attractor:**

> {2.81612, Null}

---

**EDIT2:** All computations were performed without any parallelization. In cases when `ParallelTable` was used to compute `my` and `classic` (i.e., employing the definitions in `corr` and `corrSum`, respectively), a 3x speed-up was achieved on a 4-core machine.

In case of obtaining `mySA` with parallelization, the speed-up was only by 14%.

Answer (score 6):

Appendix 1 of Mario Martelli's *Introduction to Discrete Dynamical Systems and Chaos* contains sample Mathematica code (pages 290-296) which should help you
http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9781118032879.app1 (free, click 'Get PDF')

Also, the Wolfram Library Archive contains sample code in *Testing Chaos and Fractal Properties in Economic Time Series* computes these quantities for 1,000 data points.
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6162/

Comment: In case anyone wants to follow the second lead, the linked file seems inaccessible, but you can get it through the Internet Wayback Machine at (http://web.archive.org/web/20100821131053/http://www.internationalmathematicasymposium.org/IMS99/paper25/ims99paper25.nb).  It's a bit hard to understand, but it looks like they might be implementing the [Wolf et al. 1985](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167278985900119) algorithm for calculating Lyapunov exponents from a time series.

Comment: That Wolf et al. 1985 algorithm has also been ported to [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48084-lyapunov-exponent-estimation-from-a-time-series-documentation-added).  Hope someone follows up on this to provide a nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative  way of using `Nearest` gives over 15X speed-up over `corrSA` in corey979's answer:

```
ClearAll[corrNearest]
corrNearest[data_, r_] := Module[{nF = Nearest[data -> "Index"]},
  Total[Table[UnitStep[nF[data[[i]], {All, r}]- i - 1], {i, 1, Length[data]}], 2]]
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 2000;
data = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
res = Log10 @ N @ Table[{r, corrNearest[data, r]}, {r, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]; //
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.104299

```
mySA = Log10 @ N @ Table[{r, corrSA[data, r]}, {r, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.651286

```
res == mySA
```

> True

For `n = 3000` the timings are `2.75211` for `corrSA` and `0.132438` for `corrNearest`.

Comment: Which version of MMA does this apply to? MMA 11.0.1.0 (win10 64 bit) seems not to like data->"Index" (and tbh I don't understand what that is doing). I get "Index is neither a list of real points not a valid list of rules" when I use corrNearest (Code just copy/pasted...)

Comment: @Julian, I think it was v10 (wolfram cloud)  when this was posted. Just tried teh same code  in version 12 (wolfram cloud) and it works. The form `data -> "Index"` is introduced in version 10; it should work in later versions. The form `data ->Automatic` works in version 9 and newer versions and it does the same thing, that is, `Nearest[data ->"Index"][x]` and `Nearest[data ->Automatic][x]` both give  the _position(s)_  of the element in `data` that is closest to `x`.

Comment: I see you also said it was available in 11 in this Q https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25273/creating-a-nearestfunction-that-returns-an-index but it does not seem to work for me. (checked with fresh kernel) However data->Automatic does. Thanks

Comment: @Julian, it is probably a glitch introduced in the   MMA 11.0.1.0 release fixed later.