# Accelerating the construction of a ParallelTable

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, parallelization, packed-arrays

I wish to calculate a rather dense antisymmetric matrix quite fast based on a random distribution of points (and their radii) in the three dimensional space as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
n = 12; size = n*n*n;
Print["The size of the matrix is = ", size];
grid = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {size, 3}];
epsilon = 5.2; cl = 6.;
xgrid2 = Map[First, grid];
ygrid2 = Map[(#[[2]]) &, grid];
zgrid2 = Map[Last, grid];
rad[k_, l_] := EuclideanDistance[grid[[k]], grid[[l]]]
mat1 = ParallelTable[With[{radial = rad[i, j]},
     If[radial <= epsilon, -((
       56 Max[cl - radial, 
         0]^5 (cl + 5 radial) (xgrid2[[i]] - xgrid2[[j]]))/cl^8), 0]]
    , {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}]; // AbsoluteTiming
AntisymmetricMatrixQ[mat1]
```

Unfortunately, although I used `ParallelTable`, it seems it requires a considerable time when the size of the matrix is high, e.g., when $n=25$ and the size would be $15625$!

So, I would be thankful if someone could provide a couple of comments in order to accelerate such a process.

Comment: First comment after a first glance: built-in functions are usually faster. Instead defining `rad[]`, you could employ `EuclideanDistance`.

Comment: Thanks. This has been done. But the computational time is still high.

Comment: `grid` are points within a unit cube, so the maximal distance that can be achieved is $\sqrt{3}\approx 1.73$; why do you test whether `radial <= epsilon`? It always will.

Comment: I revised the sample code for the general case. In general, the bounds for the cube could be any number. I think the anti-symmetric feature or an application of `Compile[]` can help us.

Comment: Employing `Nearest` can substantially speed it up; see the beginning of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125543/22013).

Comment: How do you want to apply `Nearest` for constructing the matrix here? Please write your comment in a piece of implementation.

Comment: I'm attempting to find only elements that are not zero, and define the lacking ones as zeros.

Comment: It seems that indeed my idea to use `Nearest` does not make the code faster, or at least I cannot employ it efficiently. So my last remarks are: (1) get rid of `xgrid2`, `ygrid2`, `zgrid2`; (2) replace `(xgrid2[[i]] - xgrid2[[j]])` with `grid[[i, 1]] - grid[[j, 1]])`, and (3) compute the `ParallelTable` only for `{j,i+1,size}`, pad the rest with zeros and add to it a transposed and multiplied by $-1$ matrix. This should speed up the computation by a factor of two (the whole code for `n=25` run 6 mins, so it easily be reduced to 3 mins).

Comment: Please submit your third comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can speed this up a lot by using that `radial <= epsilon` means only a small fraction of all those matrix elements have to be considered. Here's how I would do that:

```
computeMatrix[grid_, xgrid2_, size_] := Module[{dist, diff, eliminate, pos, values, gr = ConstantArray[xgrid2, size]},
  dist = DistanceMatrix[grid, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
  diff = gr - Transpose[gr];
  eliminate = UnitStep[ConstantArray[epsilon, {size, size}] - dist];
  pos = SparseArray[eliminate]["NonzeroPositions"];
  dist = Extract[dist, pos];
  diff = Extract[diff, pos];
  values = ((56 Clip[cl - dist, {0, \[Infinity]}]^5 (cl + 5 dist) diff)/cl^8);
  SparseArray[pos -> values]
]

mat1 == computeMatrix[grid, xgrid2, size]
(* True *)
```

This evaluates in approximately 0.1 seconds on my computer, more than 100 times faster than the original solution.

[Marius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22099/marius-ladeg%c3%a5rd-meyer) provided the vectorized function in the second to last line in a comment below. (If there is interest, one can see this solution without with a non-vectorized function in the edit history of this post.)

**Note:** This is a very memory hungry function for large $n$. A typical symptom for lack of memory is that the operating system is sluggish or non-responsive while the computation is ongoing. I might update this later with an improvement directed at memory efficiency, but if memory is a problem is might also be a good idea to ask a question about how this can be optimized with regards to memory. It also appears that the speed up with the vectorized approach as compared to my previous approach is lost when the computation is memory constrained.

Comment: An amazing response. Thanks. Just one query. When I choose $n=25$, your code (without compiling) makes my laptop to get frozen! May you please report the whole time required for the case $n=25$ in your system?

Comment: @M.J.2 It takes about 75 seconds on my computer. If the laptop freezes it may be due to lack of memory, so you may have to take that into consideration as well.

Comment: How about using a vectorized function? Just uncompiled `values = ((56 Clip[cl - dist, {0, \[Infinity]}]^5 (cl + 5 dist) diff)/cl^8)` gives the same result as your `MapThread` and takes 0.024 seconds. Your's give 0.7 on my machine as well.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yup! This is what I wanted to do, never got to it. I updated the post to reflect this great improvement.

Comment: @M.J.2 With the new function it took me 106 seconds to compute for $n=25$ and I maxed out my 16 GB memory. If you have less than 16 GB memory, I'm not sure if you can run it and if you can run it the speed will suffer I guess.

Comment: This modified response is really great. Yes, I am using 8 GB of RAM in my machine and I think because of that my machine freezes for the cases higher than $n=23$. The most memory-consuming portion of the code is `gr = ConstantArray[xgrid2, size]` and `gr - Transpose[gr]` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

While [C. E.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126054/22013) is outperforming my solution, I thought I'll elaborate on [my last comment to the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126042/accelerating-the-construction-of-a-paralleltable#comment341173_126042) for the sake of completeness.

First, `xgrid2, ygrid2, zgrid2` are not needed, and the differences `xgrid2[[i]] - xgrid2[[j]]` might be written as `grid[[i, 1]] - grid[[j, 1]]`. Next, `With` is also not necessary. And finally, the main point is that the computed matrix is antisymmetric **by construction**, so one only needs to compute half of it:

```
mat1 = ParallelTable[
    If[rad[i, j] <= epsilon, 
        -((56 Max[cl - rad[i, j], 0]^5 (cl + 5 rad[i, j]) (grid[[i, 1]] - grid[[j, 1]]))/cl^8),0],
{i, 1, size}, {j, i + 1, size}]; // AbsoluteTiming

mat2 = PadLeft[mat1, {size, size}]; // AbsoluteTiming
mat3 = mat2 - Transpose@mat2; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The above is overall two times faster than the original code; `mat1` takes 2/3 of the total time, while `mat3` takes the remaining (the `Transpose` appears to be quite time-consuming; `mat2` requires a negligible amount of time. So in fact the crucial information that is contained in `mat1` can be obtained 3x faster than with the original code.

Comment: Why the output matrix `mat3` in your response is different to the original output matrix `mat1` in the question?

Comment: It's not; I just run it to verify. Note that I also used `mat1` to name a matrix, but it's different than yours. Maybe you're overriding definitions and in fact comparing my `mat3` to my `mat1`, which are of course different. Change `mat1` in your code to `mat` and run `mat==mat3`.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. The matrices are the same. Do you know why `Transpose` is slow for large matrices! Furthermore, `With[]` is required, since in your way, `rad[i, j]`is computed more than once for each entry! Am I right?

Comment: No and it puzzles me, especially when you take `m = UpperTriangularize@RandomReal[1, {n^3, n^3}]; trm = m - Transpose@m; // AbsoluteTiming` - so the same operation as in the code, the same size, reals as elements etc. - it works much faster for such random matrix.