# Making calculation of correlation dimension faster

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, compile

I am trying to make my calculation faster. I was hoping, when I
compiled it, it would work much faster, but in the end its
even slower. I don't know if I am using `Compile` correctly. I am open to any suggestion on how to make this computation faster.

I use the data:

```
DD = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 3}];
```

I have written the following function for calculating correlation dimension (D2):

```
CORRDIM[data_] := (
  m = 
    ParallelTable[{r, 
    Total[
      Table[
        Length[Drop[Nearest[Drop[data, i - 1], data[[i]], {All, r}], 1]], 
        {i, 1, Length[data]}]]}, {r, 0.001, 0.011, 0.001}];
  m);
```

`CORRDIM` works pretty fast, but for a large dataset it is still too slow.

```
CORRDIM[DD]; // AbsoluteTiming  

{0.483119, Null}
```

I was hoping that `Compile` could help me speed up this calculation,
especially that the options

```
CompilationTarget -> "C", 
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
Parallelization -> True
```

would somehow run the code in multiple threads, but the compile version works even slower than the interpreted version.

```
fcc = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
    Table[
      {r, 
       Total[
         Table[
           Length[Drop[Nearest[Drop[x, i - 1], x[[i]], {All, r}], 1]], 
           {i, 1, Length[x]}]]}, {r, 0.001, 0.011, 0.001}], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True]`

Map[fcc, {DD}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.787973, Null}
> ```

Is it there any way to make it faster? Am I making some mistakes in the use of `Compile`?

Comment: Which definition of "correlation dimension" do you use? [The one I found](http://public.lanl.gov/jt/Papers/box-assisted-correlation.pdf) seems to be different than what you programmed. The correlation integral in that article, $C(N,r)$, can be computed with matrix arithmetic. (Much faster than using `Nearest`.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I believe your issue of having slower compiled code comes from the fact that Nearest isn’t compilable.

Comment: Related: [(125543)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125543/22013)

Answer (score 10):

Here is my take on this... I am following the definitions and computational steps given in the article

[1] James Theiler, ["Efficient algorithm for estimating the correlation dimension from a set of discrete points"](http://public.lanl.gov/jt/Papers/box-assisted-correlation.pdf), 
Phys. Rev. A 36, 4456 – Published 1 November 1987. DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.36.4456 .

Make data:

```
SeedRandom[33435]
n = 1000;
DD = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}];
Dimensions[DD]

(* {1000, 3} *)
```

Compute the distance matrix and take the upper triangular values:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 dmat = DistanceMatrix[DD];
 dvals = SparseArray[
   SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[dmat, 1]]["NonzeroValues"]];
]

(* {0.051459, Null} *)
```

Define the correlation dimension integral function:

```
Clear[CDIntegral]
CDIntegral[dvals_SparseArray, n_Integer, r_?NumericQ] :=      
  Block[{res},
   res = Total@UnitStep[r - dvals];
   res*2./(n*(n - 1))
  ];
```

Note that the function `CDIntegral` is defined in such a way so `dvals` can be reused.

Compute the correlation integrals for a range of distance values.

```
rRange = Range[0.001, 0.011, 0.001];

AbsoluteTiming[
 res =Table[CDIntegral[dvals, n, r], {r, rRange}];
]

(* {0.034141, Null} *)
```

This seems to be ~10 times faster, than using `Nearest` (on my recent MacBook Pro with `$Version` 11.2.0.)

Using `n=10000` the above computations are done for ~20 seconds.

Following [[1](http://public.lanl.gov/jt/Papers/box-assisted-correlation.pdf)] here is how the correlation dimension is estimated with the results obtained from the computations above:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[
  Log@Select[Transpose[{rRange, res}], #[[2]] > 0 &], {1, x}, x]
lm["BestFitParameters"][[2]]

 (* 2.68916 *)
```

Here is a plot of the found correlation integrals and the fit:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{Transpose[{rRange,res}], {#, Exp[lm["Function"][Log[#]]]} & /@ rRange}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotLegends -> {"correlation integrals", "fit"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[corrDIM]
corrDIM[data_] := Module[{nF = Nearest[data -> "Index"]},
  Table[ {r, Tr[Table[Tr[UnitStep[nF[data[[i]], {All, r}]- i - 1]], 
   {i, 1, Length[data]}]]}, {r, 0.001, 0.011, 0.001}]]
```

Using Anton's example data:

```
SeedRandom[33435]
n = 1000;
DD = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}];

First @ AbsoluteTiming[result = corrDIM[DD];]
```

> 0.044153

Comparing with OP's `CORRDIM` (on Wolfram Cloud where `ParallelTable` is not supported):

```
Quiet @ First @ AbsoluteTiming[result2 = CORRDIM[DD];]
```

> 0.192319

```
result == result2
```

> True

Comparing with Anton's `CDIntegral`:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[dmat = DistanceMatrix[DD];
 dvals = SparseArray[ SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[dmat, 1]]["NonzeroValues"]];
 res = Table[CDIntegral[dvals, n, r], {r, rRange}];]
```

> 0.07153

```
2./(n*(n - 1)) result[[All, 2]] == res
```

> True

Comment: Nice, much faster than my implementation, especially with larger `n`, e.g. `n=10000`.

Comment: Thanks, can but I have a problem, I can not run your corrDIM function, ther is  an error with "Index", what does this mean  please  '  Nearest[data -> "Index"] '  ? I couldnt find out.

Comment: Actually this helps me already, but originally I was trying to run computing of more of Datasets in threads, by using any of D2 estimating methods. I mean for example for  all Datasets DD, DD1 DD2 ... DDn at once so it would take like the same time as for one DD. Is it possible ? I think  using 
     Compile  it should work somehow, but I cant find out how.

Comment: @Mark, you can use `Automatic` in place of `"Index"` in versions before 10.  Re parallelization / compile, `Compile` might make  Anton's method faster.